# Calling a class function from main with parameters

Tags: c++, function, class

I am trying to pass some variables from my main function into a class that I have made which will later let me store the inputs inn a file. I want to be able to have multiple different objects stored, up to around 20.

```
int main(){

int a[20];
float b[20];
string c[20];
string d[20];
string name[20];
char contin;
menu MyMenu;

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    cout << "Please enter the name of the item: ";
    cin >> name[i];
    cout << "\nPlease enter a value: ";
    cin >> a[i];
    cout << "\nPlease enter a value: ";
    cin >> b[i];
    cout << "\nPlease enter a phrase: ";
    cin >> c[i];
    cout << "\nPlease enter a a phrase: ";
    cin >> d[i];
    cout << "\n\nWould you like to go through the list again?(y/n): ";
    cin >> contin;
    cout << "\n";
    if(contin == 'N' || 'n'){
        break;
    };
};
void MyMenu.storeitem(a[20], b[20], c[20], d[20]);`};`
```

This is currently my main function which has a loop and then stores the inputs into an array.

The line that I having trouble with is last line where i am trying to pass it all to the class function.

Below is the class

```
class menu{
    public:
    void storeitem(int a[20], float b[20], string c[20], string d[20]);
};
void menu::storeitem(int a[20], float b[20], string c[20], string d[20]){

    int storeb[20];
    int storea[20];
    string storec[20];
    string stored[20];

    storeb[20] = b[20];
    storea[20] = a[20];
    storec[20] = c[20];
    stored[20] = d[20];
};
```

I think the problem is in the last line of the main function where I am trying to call the class function.

Comment: `storeb[20] = b[20];` etc. are accessing out-of-bounds. Do not dot that!

Comment: Read 30 items in 20-element array? Another out-of-bounds access!

Comment: My bad I only want it to read up to 20, ill edit

Comment: what do you mean by it is out of bounds `storeb[20] = b[20];`, can you not store variables you have passed in main in a class function?

Comment: Of course you can. Just you are doing wrong.

Comment: Do you write `char msg[] = "Hello world!"; int printf("%s"[3], msg[13]);`?

Comment: The variable is called `a`. Not `a[20]`. And the function is called with `MyMenu.storeitem`, not `void MyMenu.storeitem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You won't need `void` or `` ` `` to call functions.
- `storeb[20] = b[20];` and such things are not how to copy arrays but nonsense with out-of-range access.
- Do not do out-of-range access and match the type of expected arguments and what is passed.
- Using magic numbers is not good because it raises risk of making typo or forgettng to change some of the values.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

const int MAX = 20;

class menu{
    public:
    void storeitem(int a[MAX], float b[MAX], string c[MAX], string d[MAX]);
};
void menu::storeitem(int a[MAX], float b[MAX], string c[MAX], string d[MAX]){

    int storeb[MAX];
    int storea[MAX];
    string storec[MAX];
    string stored[MAX];

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        storeb[i] = b[i];
        storea[i] = a[i];
        storec[i] = c[i];
        stored[i] = d[i];
    }

    // do something with what is stored
}

int main(){

    int a[MAX] = {0};
    float b[MAX] = {0};
    string c[MAX];
    string d[MAX];
    string name[MAX];
    char contin;
    menu MyMenu;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        cout << "Please enter the name of the item: ";
        cin >> name[i];
        cout << "\nPlease enter a value: ";
        cin >> a[i];
        cout << "\nPlease enter a value: ";
        cin >> b[i];
        cout << "\nPlease enter a phrase: ";
        cin >> c[i];
        cout << "\nPlease enter a a phrase: ";
        cin >> d[i];
        cout << "\n\nWould you like to go through the list again?(y/n): ";
        cin >> contin;
        cout << "\n";
        if(contin == 'N' || 'n'){
            break;
        }
    }
    MyMenu.storeitem(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Comment: `if(contin == 'N' || 'n')` is a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the size of the arrays as parameters in the storeitem function. However you should add a count this is represented by int i, as the last parameter.

```
void menu::storeitem(int a[], float b[], string c[], string d[], int i){
```

add the i++; to the inside at the bottom of your loop this will keep how many full times they went through and entered data. you now also have to pass i as an argument when you are calling your function.

```
cin >> contin;
    i++;
    if((contin == 'n') || contin == 'N'){
            break;
    }
}
MyMenu.storeitem(a, b, c, d, i);
```

What Are You Trying To Accomplish here?
Are you trying to store the contents that we put in array b into storeb?
All these statements are saying make the 20th element in stroreb, storea, etc... equal to whatever the 20th element of the parameters we passed into the function. Some more information would be greatly appreciated.

```
storeb[20] = b[20];
storea[20] = a[20];
storec[20] = c[20];
stored[20] = d[20];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part, did not know i did not specify the size.

Comment: As for the second bit, I realize it is wrong now and I now have a loop, it was meant to basically make array1 = array2, so then i can use that array to save and edit the input in a text file

Comment: so you are virtually trying to place all the contents in array b into storeb? Why not just place all the contents of array b into a text file? @Thecube

Comment: There is not really a practical use for it yet, just trying to play around with classes and learn how everything works

Comment: If you want to fill the contents of b into store b, I suggest using a for loop to read in each data item